# How to EFFICIENTLY find out what the number in ordinal is?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Here is an example :

1. 4 digits
2. first, second digit's range is : 0 ~ 5 (total six number)
3. third, fourth digit's range is : 0 ~ 4 (total five number)

So, 0000, 0040, 0111, 4455 are ok but 5555, 4555, 4466 are not ok.

What I want to is to find **what is the 2345 in ordinal? (from start zero index)`**

For example, 0001 is "1" in ordinal. Likewise, 0010 is "5".

It could be calculated by,

> (5*6*6*1)*2   + (6*6*1)*3 + (6*1)*4 + (1)*5 = 497

I made a function in `Python`

```
import numpy as np

def find_real_index_of_state(state, num_cnt_in_each_digit):
    """
    parameter
    =========
    state(str) 
    num_cnt_in_each_digit(list) : the number of number in each digit
    """
    num_of_digit = len(state)
    digit_list = [int(i) for i in state]   

    num_cnt_in_each_digit.append(1)

    real_index = 0
    for i in range(num_of_digit):
        real_index += np.product(num_cnt_in_each_digit[num_of_digit-i:]) * digit_list[num_of_digit-i-1]
    return real_index

find_real_index_of_state("2345", [5,5,6,6])
```

Its result is same as 497.

Problem is though, this function is really slow. I need much more faster version, but this one is the best I can think about.

I really need your advice to improve it performance. (e.g vectorization etc)

Thanks

Comment: FYI, I think what you're describing is a [mixed-base number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems#Mixed_bases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope I understood you correctly.

First thing I notice is you do not need to recalculate everything each loop. I.e. you calculate (5*6*6*1),(6*6*1),(6*1),(1) individually instead you only need to calculate once.

```
def find_real_index_of_state(state,num_cnt_in_each_digit):

    factor = 1

    total = 0

    for digit, num_cnt in zip(reversed(state), reversed(num_cnt_in_each_digit)):

        digit = int(digit)

        total += digit*factor

        factor*= num_cnt

    return total
```

Comment: This one is 10 times faster than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one vectorized approach making use of [`np.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) to perform the iterative `np.product` and then [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the sum-reductions -

```
def real_index_vectorized(n, count):
    num = [int(d) for d in str(n)]
        # Or np.array([n]).view((str,1)).astype(int) #Thanks to @Eric
        # Or (int(n)//(10**np.arange(len(n)-1,-1,-1)))%10
    return np.dot( np.cumprod(count[:0:-1]), num[-2::-1]) + num[-1]
```

Runtime test -

1) Original sample :

```
In [66]: %timeit find_real_index_of_state("2345",[5,5,6,6])
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop

In [67]: %timeit real_index_vectorized("2345",[5,5,6,6])
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.19 µs per loop
```

2) A bit bigger sample :

```
In [69]: %timeit find_real_index_of_state("234532321321323",[5,5,6,6,3,5,4,6,4,5,2,3,5,3,3])
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.7 µs per loop

In [70]: %timeit real_index_vectorized("234532321321323",[5,5,6,6,3,5,4,6,4,5,2,3,5,3,3])
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop
```

Being a vectorized solution, it would scale well when it competes against a loopy version that has a *good* number of loop iterations.

Comment: This needs to be `view('U1')` in python 3, if you want it to work on `str` and not just bytes

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the improvement on it! Updated

Comment: Thanks for very expertic(?) answer. It works right but performance is not that good enough.. almost  similar with mine... @Edd Saunders answer is 10times faster!

Comment: @user3595632 Well you were looking for a vectorized solution to a problem that you are not iterating for a good number of times, like just `4` times for the given sample. As such, it would be hard to see any noticeable improvement. BUT, if you are performing this operation on a number of different values, we can certainly vectorize at that level and gain some performance improvement.

Comment: @user3595632 Added a bit more improved version.

Comment: Thanks for simple and improved version, Divakar! But If you compare with Edd Saunders's one, his one is 2~3 times faster even for long number. I mentioned that vectorization method could be one of method "to improve performance".... By the way, your method helps me a lot studying vectorization and how to make simple code!!

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I propose you vectorize your states first  :

```
base=np.array([5*6*6,6*6,6,1])
states=np.array(["2345","0010"])
numbers=np.frombuffer(states,np.uint32).reshape(-1,4)-48 # faster
ordinals=(base*numbers).sum(1)
#array([497,   6], dtype=int64)
```